# Updating, Deleting, Editing data

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

My English is bad. Sorry. I'm sure you understand what I mean.
The codes I share below question whether there is new content, and if so, add the new content to the page. But I do not know what logic is needed to update or delete the same or a different (id). How can I make updates and deletions?

index.php

```
<?php require "ayar.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery Ajax ile Anlık Veri Güncelleme Uygulaması</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    ul, li {padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; font: 14px Arial}
    ul li {padding: 5px; background: #eee; margin-bottom: 5px}
    ul li.new {background: lightgreen}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM veri ORDER BY veri_id DESC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
        echo '<li id="'.$row->veri_id.'">'.$row->veri_text.'</li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>

<div id="sonuc"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

    require "ayar.php";

    if ($_POST){

        $lastid = $_POST["lastid"];
        if (!$lastid){
            $array["hata"] = "Geçersiz işlem!";
        } else {

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM veri WHERE veri_id > $lastid ORDER BY veri_id DESC");
            if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                    $array["veriler"] = '<li class="new" id="'.$row->veri_id.'">'.$row->veri_text.'</li>';
                }
            }

        }

        echo json_encode($array);

    }

?>
```

ajax.js

```
$(function () {

    $ajaxLoad = function () {

        var lastid = $("ul li:first").attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {"lastid": lastid},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    $("#result").html(result);

                }
                else{
                    $("ul").prepend(result.data);
                }
            }

        });
    }
    setInterval("ajaxLoad()",5000);
```

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript with jQuery you can:

- Use `$( "selector" ).length` to check if an element exists
- Use `$( "selector" ).remove()` to remove an item.
- Use `$( "selector" ).html()` to update the contents.

Where selector is a rowid (example: `#123`)

So in your success handler you could replace `$("ul").prepend(result.data);` with:

1. something to get a list of existing `<li>` `id` (example: `idList = jQuery.map(jQuery("ul li"),function(e){return e.id})`)
2. something to check if the new result exists (example:  `idList.indexOf(results.data.test(/id="(.*?)"/) > 0`)

...then decide whether to insert/update/remove into the list.

Comment: I do not know where to add the code and how to run it. I just started. I did not write the above codes myself. Can you help me? Should not be difficult?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you are updating or loading data through ajax query in every 5 seconds. `$ajaxLoad()` is a function not a string. so your setInterval function should be this

```js
        setInterval($ajaxLoad(), 5000)
```

**For deletion the same or different id:** 
 when you want to do it? After any specific action like `click`, If yes then you can do that through ajax query too.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your ajax.js your missing the dollar sign $ on the function name, you should have `setInterval("$ajaxLoad()",5000);`